# How to start url rewriting in With wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How to rewrite
 **`www.freeonlineoffers.com/?page=183&offers=xiaomi_smart_phone`**
 to 
**`www.freeonlinbeoffers.com/xiaomi_smart_phone`** in wordpress.

I am very confused to proceed it, so please suggest me as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I seems that you want seo friendly url so for that you should use permalink.
For more information about permalink use : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WordPress Rewrite Rule](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) and [WordPress Rewrite Tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag) to alter your desired URL.

```
function custom_rewrite_tag()
{
    add_rewrite_tag('%page%', '([a-z0-9\-]+)');

}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
add_action('init', 'seo_friendly');
function seo_friendly()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('^page/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?page=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
```

Don't forget to update permalink after pasting above code.

Comment: But where should I past it?

Comment: I have current url is: www.example.com/deals/?offer=lumia-smart-phone.         And how i change it to www.example.com/deals/lumia-smart-phone.Please provide a exact clue.